# Mongoose: Set field in schema using search query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

So.. I was wondering if in Mongoose I could do something like this:

```
var Match = require('./models/Match);    

ClubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  playedMatches: //Search query for played matches here (so like Match.find())
});
```

So I want the playedMatches field to be filled when I use a query to search a club. Right now I use sort of a "Singleton type way" to fill the playedMatches field like so:

```
ClubSchema.playedMatches = null;

ClubSchema.methods.setPlayedMatches = function (callback) {
  var self = this;
  Match.find({$or: [{homeClub: self._id}, {awayClub: self._id}], matchOver: true}).sort({playDate: 'asc'}).exec(function (err, matches) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      self.playedMatches = matches;
      callback(false, matches);
    }
  });
};

ClubSchema.methods.getPlayedMatches = function (callback) {
  if (!this.playedMatches) {
    this.setPlayedMatches(function (err, matches) {
      if (err) {
      callback(err);
      } else {
        callback(false, matches);
      }
    });
  } else {
    callback(false, this.playedMatches);
  }
};
```

But because I want things to go asynchronous that doesn't really work and I don't want to have to call a method to set the playedMatches field first before I use any other function that uses the playedMatches field cause well.. That's just ugly too..

the MatchSchema looks like this:

```
var MatchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  homeClub: {type: String, ref: 'Club'},
  awayClub: {type: String, ref: 'Club'},
  playDate: {type: Date, required: true},
  goalsHomeClub: {type: Number},
  goalsAwayClub: {type: Number},
  matchOver: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
```

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Are playedMatches stored in a different collection? Please post the code you are currently using as well.

Comment: Yes, they are stored in the collection "matches" and clubs are stored in the collection "clubs".

Comment: Could you post the schema and model code for the match collection as well?

Answer (score 2):

Mongoose has an inbuilt way for this called [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

All you need to do is mention the model name in the ref field of the field specification. The model name has to be the same as written in the Mongoose.model method.

```
ClubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  name: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  playedMatches: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Match'}]
});
```

You can now populate the matches in the field automatically after a query with the following code:

```
Club.find({}).populate('playedMatches');
```

Comment: Thnx for your quick answer! I am familiar with populate. However I can't seem to use that to make this work. Populate always looks at the id of another object. Plus I don't want to have to put all the relevant matchIds for a club in its object. That doesn't make things much more flexible.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, and I think you have already implemented it the best way possible. You cannot define a virtual field either as they cannot be asynchronous.

Comment: Darn*t! I was afraid of that! It just doesn't feel right this way :|. Oh well, thank you so much for your time though!